# Is setting up MySQL much harder on Windows than Linux?

Tags: mysql, windows, database

I have spent hours just trying to set up MySQL and still no success(on windows). I am starting to doubt my very name.

When I try to configure it says:

"The security settings could not be applied. Error Number 1045. Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (usin passwrd: NO)

And before it kept rejecting my password.

Comment: What package or installer did you use to install mysql?

Comment: mysql-5.5.11-win32 + mysql-workbench-gpl-5.2.33b-win32 (for windows)

Comment: I keep having issues with it. It's asking about this/that/etc. and in the end it chokes. I guess I might have to read all I can online..

Answer (score 1):

http://www.wampserver.com/en/download.php

Use it, love it, stop wasting time and get programming!

OR YOU CAN TRY THIS....

If you actually have set a root password and you've just lost/forgotten it:

Stop MySQL
Restart it manually with the skip-grant-tables option: mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables

Run the MySQL client: mysql -u root

Reset the root password manually with this MySQL command: UPDATE mysql.user SET

Password=PASSWORD('password') WHERE User='root';

Flush the privileges with this MySQL command: FLUSH PRIVILEGES;

From http://www.tech-faq.com/reset-mysql-password.shtml

[MySQL - ERROR 1045 - Access denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/489119/mysql-error-1045-access-denied)

Answer (score 0):

I had this (frustrating) issue as well.
What I did was:

- Uninstall MySQL
- Delete the folder C:\ProgramData\MySQL\
- Install MySQL again

Hope it works for you as well.