# Another 1045 : Access denied for user 'someone'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Tags: mysql, database-connection

As lot of dummies, I cannot connect to MySQL server with user.

**This is settings of my USER in DB `mysql` table `user`**

```
Host:   %
User: someone
Password: mypassword
Select_priv, Insert_priv, Update_priv, Delete_priv, Create_priv, Drop_priv, Reload_priv, Shutdown_priv, Process_priv, File_priv, Grant_priv, References_priv, Index_priv, Alter_priv, Show_db_priv, Super_priv, Create_tmp_table_priv, Lock_tables_priv, Execute_priv, Repl_slave_priv, Repl_client_priv, Create_view_priv, Show_view_priv, Create_routine_priv, Alter_routine_priv, Create_user_priv: Y
max_questions, max_updates, max_connection, max_user_connections: 0
```

**Connection**

Im connecting via `localhost` console OR phpMyAdmin installed on this machine.

**MySQL Server**

Information from phpMyAdmin: `Server: Localhost via UNIX socket | Server version: 5.0.70-log | Protocol version: 10`

1. When mysql server is running as `mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables &` then I can connect to server as any user.
2. When mysql server is running normally as `/etc/init.d/mysqld start` then I cannot an I have error

   > 1045 : Access denied for user 'someone'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

I was spending hours to find solution in google and mysql documentation but without result. Probably it will be some essential settings. Hope you will give me some suggestion. Thanks a lot.

Comment: what happens if you specify host=hostname instead of host=localhost?

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL - ERROR 1045 - Access denied](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/489119/mysql-error-1045-access-denied)

Comment: one problem was with password. I stored it as plain text instead encrypted password('mypassword')

Comment: Second problem was/is that the `%` sign not work. I must set up `localhost` otherwise I still have `#1045 Cannot log in to the MySQL server`

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to reset the password for the someone user. It happens often.

Try to start your local server with no password check:

```
mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables
```

And then

```
set password for 'someone'@'localhost' password('new fancy password')
```

(notice the '')

See more info in the docs: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/set-password.html

This answer might also help

[MySQL - ERROR 1045 - Access denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/489119/mysql-error-1045-access-denied)

Comment: thanx this was one of the problem. I stored password as plain text not encrypted with password('mypassword').