# Can't login to mysql when mysql is run by xampp control

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, xampp

I have sucessfuly reseted my root password on my localhost xampp. Now when I run the mysql daemon myself ( `XAMPP/mysql/bin/mysqld.exe` ), I can login with PHPMyAdmin to the MySQL administration with no problem.

However when I run MySQL from XAMPP's Control Panel (the "nice" window with start/stop etc. buttons)

I can't login through PHPMyAdmin anymore - I get error  #1045...

This must be something configuration-related? What might be causing this?

Big thanks :)

Comment: Try `Get-WmiObject Win32_Process -Filter "name = 'mysqld.exe'"` and check the command line arguments. Maybe it's even another binary?

Comment: Sorry, that is a powershell command. You could also try [process explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx).

Comment: XAMPP's got these `--defaults-file="myXamppLocation\mysql\bin\my.ini" --standalone` - but what in these options is "fighting" against the login?

Comment: Check the specified ini file for related settings?

Comment: It is not caused by the `--standalone` param, It is caused by the `my.ini` file - contents: http://ideone.com/6HsXBF - I read through it but still can't figure out what might be causing it :/ can you ? :)

Comment: I'm afraid not. I assume you tried http://stackoverflow.com/questions/489119/mysql-error-1045-access-denied and checked the logfile for errors?

Comment: @andy I finaly solved it, but It could not be done without your help - so many thanks :) I will use that powershell command many times again.

Comment: Credit to http://superuser.com/questions/415360/how-do-i-find-out-command-line-arguments-of-a-running-program ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that mysql daemon in xampp has different default value for the basedir than the `my.ini` setting file.

So when I've reseted the password without adding the same `--defaults-file` as XAMPP does when it runs mysqld - I actually reseted a password for a different "workspace".

**Thanks** to @andy, because his comments led me to the solution :)

So the right way to reset XAMPP's MySQL root user *( on Windows )* is:

## 1) Stop MySQL with XAMPP Control

## 2) Prepare init file

Create file called `mysql-init.txt` directly on `C:\` drive and fill it with this content:

```
#INSERT INTO mysql.user (User,Password) VALUES('root',PASSWORD('root'));
UPDATE mysql.user SET Password=PASSWORD('root') WHERE User='root';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON * . * TO 'root'@'localhost';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

- `#` is a comment - if you did not have a root user or deleted it by accident - uncomment the first line and comment the second line

These commands create a MySQL **user** *"root"* with **password** *"root"* and **give him/her ALL privileges** on ***everything***.

## 3) Run MySQL daemon with proper params

Run `YOUR_XAMPP_INSTALL\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe` with these params:

***Note the double slashes "\\" instead of single slashes "\"***

```
--defaults-file="c:\\YOUR_XAMPP_INSTALL\\mysql\\bin\\my.ini"
--init-file=C:\\mysql-init.txt
```

So the whole command for `cmd.exe` could look like:

```
c:\YOUR_XAMPP_INSTALL\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe --defaults-file="c:\\YOUR_XAMPP_INSTALL\\mysql\\bin\\my.ini" --init-file=C:\\mysql-init.txt
```

Of course replace `YOUR_XAMPP_INSTALL` with the path to your custom xampp install ( very often it is just "xampp" resp. "C:\xampp"). And of course if you are operating on a different drive than "C", change `C:\` to `WhatEverLetterYouWant:\`

## 4) Try to login on `http://localhost/phpmyadmin/`

Try to login on `http://localhost/phpmyadmin/` with user *root* and password *root*, if it does not work, you have done something wrong in the previous 3 steps

## 5) 4) went fine? => Stop MySQL with XAMPP Control

## 6) Start MySQL with XAMPP control

## 7) Try to login again with root/root

## 8) 7) went fine? => Done :)

**References:**

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/resetting-permissions.html

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-a-new-user-and-grant-permissions-in-mysql