# ERROR 1044 (42000): Access denied for user

Tags: mysql

I created a new user with a password in MySQL.

```
mysql> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON simple_cms_development.*
    -> TO 'simple_cms'@'localhost'
    -> IDENTIFIED BY 'xxxxxxx';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.04 sec)
```

I checked that it was created:

```
mysql> SHOW GRANTS FOR 'simple_cms'@'localhost';
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for simple_cms@localhost                                                                                   |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'simple_cms'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*CA931C969BFB20B345B153F9AE0B3EBC543B48EF' |
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `simple_cms_development`.* TO 'simple_cms'@'localhost'                                    |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I attempted to sign in as that user and received a 1044 error:

```
 Macintosh-2:simple_cms kmcrayton7$ mysql -u simple_cms -p simple_csm_development;
    Enter password: 
    ERROR 1044 (42000): Access denied for user 'simple_cms'@'localhost' to database 'simple_csm_development'
```

Followed the steps in answer [#1 and #6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/489119/mysql-error-1045-access-denied) and here is the result:

```
mysql> select user,host,password from mysql.user;
+------------+-----------+-------------------------------------------+
| user       | host      | password                                  |
+------------+-----------+-------------------------------------------+
| root       | localhost | *986BD1453A6B2F3CCF85DC695B981EE516B7613D |
| root       | macintosh | *986BD1453A6B2F3CCF85DC695B981EE516B7613D |
| root       | 127.0.0.1 | *986BD1453A6B2F3CCF85DC695B981EE516B7613D |
| root       | ::1       | *986BD1453A6B2F3CCF85DC695B981EE516B7613D |
|            | localhost |                                           |
|            | macintosh |                                           |
| simple_csm | localhost | *CA931C969BFB20B345B153F9AE0B3EBC543B48EF |
| simple_cms | localhost | *CA931C969BFB20B345B153F9AE0B3EBC543B48EF |
+------------+-----------+-------------------------------------------+
8 rows in set (0.04 sec)

mysql> exit
Bye
Macintosh-2:simple_cms kmcrayton7$ mysql -u simple_cms -p simple_csm_development;
Enter password: 
ERROR 1044 (42000): Access denied for user 'simple_cms'@'localhost' to database 'simple_csm_development'


  [1]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/489119/mysql-error-1045-access-denied
```

I don't know where I'm making my mistake

I was attempting to following the suggestion below but now I can't seem to gain access at all:

```
Macintosh-2:simple_cms kmcrayton7$ mysql -u root -p
Enter password: 
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
Macintosh-2:simple_cms kmcrayton7$ mysql -u root -p
Enter password: 
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
Macintosh-2:simple_cms kmcrayton7$ mysql -u root 
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
Macintosh-2:simple_cms kmcrayton7$ mysql -u root 
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
Macintosh-2:simple_cms kmcrayton7$ mysql -u root 
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
Macintosh-2:simple_cms kmcrayton7$ mysql -u root -p
Enter password: 
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
Macintosh-2:simple_cms kmcrayton7$ mysql -u root -p
Enter password: 
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
Macintosh-2:simple_cms kmcrayton7$
```

Comment: Are you on localhost?

Comment: I don't understand your question. I have been using the localhost:3000 in the browser while following this Rails tutorial.

Answer (score 7):

I had the same issue and it solved with:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DBName.* TO 'UserName'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION;
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your user does not have the privilege to access the database of **simple_csm_development**. You need to grant privileges using the grant syntax:

> GRANT
>       priv_type [(column_list)]
>         [, priv_type [(column_list)]] ...
>       ON [object_type] priv_level
>       TO user_specification [, user_specification] ...
>       [REQUIRE {NONE | ssl_option [[AND] ssl_option] ...}]
>       [WITH {GRANT OPTION | resource_option} ...]
>
> GRANT PROXY ON user_specification
>       TO user_specification [, user_specification] ...
>       [WITH GRANT OPTION]
>
> object_type: {
>       TABLE   | FUNCTION   | PROCEDURE }
>
> priv_level: {
>       *   | *.*   | db_name.*   | db_name.tbl_name   | tbl_name   | db_name.routine_name }
>
> user_specification:
>       user [ auth_option ]
>
> auth_option: {     # Before MySQL 5.7.6
>       IDENTIFIED BY 'auth_string'   | IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD 'hash_string'   | IDENTIFIED WITH auth_plugin   | IDENTIFIED WITH
>   auth_plugin AS 'hash_string' }
>
> auth_option: {     # As of MySQL 5.7.6
>       IDENTIFIED BY 'auth_string'   | IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD 'hash_string'   | IDENTIFIED WITH auth_plugin   | IDENTIFIED WITH
>   auth_plugin BY 'auth_string'   | IDENTIFIED WITH auth_plugin AS
>   'hash_string' }
>
> ssl_option: {
>       SSL   | X509   | CIPHER 'cipher'   | ISSUER 'issuer'   | SUBJECT 'subject' }
>
> resource_option: {   | MAX_QUERIES_PER_HOUR count   |
>   MAX_UPDATES_PER_HOUR count   | MAX_CONNECTIONS_PER_HOUR count   |
>   MAX_USER_CONNECTIONS count }

[Source](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/grant.html).

Comment: I'd like to but now I am able to gain access at all

Comment: @Kim, do you have a backup of the database? Is there another user, who has access to the database?

Answer (score 0):

In all honesty, I don't know what changed but when I went through all the steps again, it worked. I'm sure there's an error on my end but I can't find it now. Thanks!