# Whats wrong with my saltstack mysql installation?

Tags: mysql, salt-stack

I am a saltstack newbie and mysql newbie too... :-/ was trying to install my-sql on Ubuntu 14. I am getting following error

[image]

I use the following sls file

```
mysql_package:
  pkg.installed:
    - name: mysql-server

mysql_conf:
  file.managed:
    - name: /etc/my.cnf
    - source: salt://mysql/files/my.cnf
    - user: root
    - group: root
    - mode: 0644
    - require:
      - pkg: mysql_package

mysql_service:
  service:
    - name: mysqld
    - running
    - enable: True
    - require:
      - pkg: mysql_conf
    - watch:
      - pkg: mysql_conf

# required packages start
server_pkgs:
  pkg:
    - installed
    - pkgs:
      - python-dev
    - refresh: True

mysql_python_pkgs:
  pkg.installed:
    - pkgs:
      - libmysqlclient-dev
      - mysql-client
      - python-mysqldb
    - require:
      - pkg: server_pkgs

python-pip:
  pkg:
    - installed
    - refresh: False

mysql:
  pip.installed:
    - require:
      - pkg: python-pip
      - pkg: mysql_python_pkg
# required package end

stg_databases:
  mysql_database.present:
    - name: stagingdb
    - require:
      - pkg: mysql
      - service: mysql_service

first_db_user:
  mysql_user.present:
    - name: stg-admin
    - password: "pass4admin"
    - host: '%'
    - connection_charset: utf8
    - saltenv:
      - LC_ALL: "en_US.utf8"
    - require:
      - mysql_database: stg_databases


create_first_table:
  mysql_query.run:
    - database: stagingdb
    - query: "create table first_table(id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY ( id ));"
    - output:   "/tmp/create_first_table.txt"
    - require:
      - mysql_database: stg_databases


first_table_grants:
  mysql_grants.present:
    - grant: all privileges
    - database: stagingdb.*
    - user: stg-admin
    - host: '%'
    - require:
      - mysql_user: first_db_user
```

And using following conf file

```
[mysqld]
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
user=mysql
symbolic-links=0

[mysqld_safe]
log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log
pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
```

Came across following link [MySQL - ERROR 1045 - Access denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/489119/mysql-error-1045-access-denied) , thats not what i want to do...

Guessing there is a relation between user defined in my.cnf and in sls file, which i am not getting correct ?

Answer (score 0):

Where there any errors when you ran this state?

Also if you run:

```
salt-call -ldebug state.sls <state file>
```

That will give you a lot of useful information as to what salt is exactly running. Is the root user still available? Can you login and see if that user was actually created?

Answer (score 0):

This is obvious Mysql GRANT issues that you don't need to debug.  It means you make some mistake of GRANTING the user. Just check the doc : https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/states/all/salt.states.mysql_user.html

mysql_user.present DOES NOT grant a user. you need **mysql_grants.present** together with mysql_user.present. The confusing part : mysql_grants.present doesn't set password; mysql_user.present set password but doesn't grant DB rights.

```
first_db_user:
  mysql_user.present:
    - name: stg-admin
    - password: "pass4admin"
    - host: '%'
    - connection_charset: utf8
    - saltenv:
      - LC_ALL: "en_US.utf8"
    - require:
      - mysql_database: stg_databases

grant_my_first_db_user:
  mysql_grants.present:
    - grant: select,insert,update
    - database: stagingdb
    - user: stg-admin
    - host: localhost
```

And saltstack mysql formula confirm this.

https://github.com/saltstack-formulas/mysql-formula/blob/master/mysql/salt-user.sls