# ERROR 1045 (28000): Unknown error 1045

Tags: mysql, linux, oracle

After Successfully Installation of mysql-community-server-5.6 on Oracle Linux the mysqld service is started. But when I connect the MySQL following error has been occur.

init.d]# service mysqld status
mysqld (pid  2563) is running...
]# mysql
]# ERROR 1045 (28000): Unknown error 1045

Please advice me how to fix this problem.

Comment: This might answer your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/489119/mysql-error-1045-access-denied

Answer (score 1):

This is probably due to invalid or missing authentication data. If you know the root (or any user) password, check if `mysql -u root -p` works or not.

If yes, you can create `/root/.my.cnf` in the following format to enable autologin.

`[client]
user=root
password='your_root_pass'`

*Some older versions of MySQL do not accept password within quotes.*