# OpenProject user unable to login to mysql

Tags: mysql, openproject

Current situation is as follows:

I have succesfully installed OpenProject on Ubuntu 14.04 server using the guide from the official website (https://www.openproject.org/open-source/download/packaged-installation-guide/). When configuring for the first time I let the configuration manager install MySQL and create the appropriate database(s).

Now I'm trying to migrate and for this to happen, I need outside access to the information_schema (schema) and database. This is supposedly done using the openproject user but I cannot seem to be able to login using this user on the commandline.

Just to be sure, I just statement below:

```
mysql -u openproject -D openproject -p
```

Then I entered the right password and press enter. It gets the default ERROR 1045.
I **am** however able to login using `root` user and `debian-sys-maint` user which was created on the initial install step. The password I used for these accounts were found in the file under "/etc/openproject/installer.dat". I am absolutely positive I use the correct password, for the application runs fine under said user.

Is there a setting in mysql that I am missing that would block users from making connection using the commandline utility?

Comment: Error 1045 means permission issue only, Refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/489119/mysql-error-1045-access-denied

Comment: Thank you Piyush Gupta for your reply. I have found that topic as well, but am quite sure that password I used was correct, since OpenProject runs fine under that user/password combination and the tables get populated as well. Do you know of any option I need to check? Just in case, I will reinstall Mysql as well.

Comment: Can you update full stacktrace on question then we can identify issue..

Comment: Solved it already Piyush Gupta. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Figured it out. In MySQL the host 127.0.0.1 and localhost are essentially different. User OpenProject by default gets assigned to host 127.0.0.1, so naturally connecting openproject@localhost did not work, though root account has different user profiles (4 to be exact) allowing it to connect to both localhost and 127.0.0.1 .

TLDR version:
Use the statement as follows:

```
mysql -u openproject -h 127.0.0.1 -p
```

Should do the trick.