# 1045 MySQL Error When it should should be working

Tags: php, mysql, apache

Config file:

```
$db=array(
            'host'      =>      'localhost',
            'user'      =>      'root',
            'pass'      =>      'secret',
            'name'      =>      'jack',
    );
```

Index file

```
$mysql = new mysqli($db['host'],$db['user'],$db['pass'],$db['name']);
$mysql->set_charset('utf8mb4'); 
if($mysql->connect_errno)
{
    die('Database connection could not be established. Error number: '.$mysql->connect_errno);
}
```

I get:

```
Database connection could not be established. Error number: 1045
```

Please guys, tell me what to do and I will respond you with the answer in 30 seconds!

UPDATE:

Okay so if i make change line to

```
$mysql = new mysqli(localhost,root,secret,jack);
```

it works, but how do I get it work with the tags?

Comment: password `lavonas` or blank? or did u include config file in index file?

Comment: Probably you will need to read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/489119/mysql-error-1045-access-denied

Comment: You are not getting any luck on this project are you.

Comment: yes there is a password in root, and the password is right. I don't know why im getting error

Comment: Can I suggest that you move this line `$mysql->set_charset('utf8mb4');` after you check the connection is OK. Dont think its the issue, but it is more logical

Comment: Try `print_r($db)` items and see if you really have them in the page, before trying to connect.

Comment: Please show all the code. Is the `$db` array in the same code file as the connection? Is the connection code inside a function/method? I am thinking SCOPE issues here

Comment: **Scope** ___Scope___ _Scope_ scope.... Oh it might be a [scoping](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) issue or then again its might be a [scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) problem

Comment: _Okay so if i make change line to

$mysql = new mysqli(localhost,root,secret,jack);
it works, but how do I get it work with the tags?_  ===> it's clear you do not have the cofig file included correctly.

Comment: **show ALL the code** not just a fragment

Comment: require_once 'include/config.php';

Comment: Thats another fragment. Amend question. Show all the code

Comment: IMA F***** IDIOT, THREAD CLOSED

Comment: *IMA F***** IDIOT, THREAD CLOSED – Petras 4 secs ago* What is this @Petras. Explain.

Comment: @NanaPartykar OP has suddenly realised what they have done wrong, and they are felling a little silly not having noticed it before. **We all been there**

Comment: So, We should also know what he did wrong? I'm curious.

Comment: Okay, so basically i was configuring wrong config file, it had same name, but were on diferent folder. So yeah on the the i were requiring it had no mysql info whatsoever and that explains everything

Comment: It is impossible for `new mysqli(localhost,root,secret,jack);` to work -- there are no quotes around the arguments!!

Answer (score 0):

Error No: 1045 refer to as Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (Using password: NO). so check you password and username for the database. Try passing the password as empty.

Comment: Addition: if you are not using Password than leave it empty, if you are using than GRANT access to user.

Comment: Working In dedicated server or in localhost @Petras?

Comment: $mysql = new mysqli(localhost,root,secret,jack); WORKS, but i need it working the way I did before..

Comment: So, when  you write directly in this function. It works. And, when you use array, it doesn't work? Correct @Petras

Comment: Naaa I would bet its a scope issue

Comment: Me too think so @RiggsFolly