# Unable to open mysql database on Mysql Query Browser mysql error 1045 access denied

Tags: mysql

Unable to open mysql database on Mysql Query Browser but i can login to same database with same credentials from command line Linux. Getting mysql error 1045 access denied.

Comment: use mySql workbench. Query Browser has been discontinued

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you actually have set a root password and you've just lost/forgotten it:

1. Stop MySQL
2. Restart it manually with the skip-grant-tables option: mysqld_safe
   --skip-grant-tables
3. Now, open a new terminal window and run the MySQL client:

   mysql -u root
4. Reset the root password manually with this MySQL command:

   `UPDATE mysql.user SET Password=PASSWORD('password') WHERE User='root';`

   If you are using MySQL 5.7 (check using mysql --version in the Terminal) then the command is:

   UPDATE mysql.user SET authentication_string=PASSWORD('password')  WHERE  User='root';
5. Flush the privileges with this MySQL command:

   FLUSH PRIVILEGES;

From http://www.tech-faq.com/reset-mysql-password.shtml

(Maybe this isn't what you need, Abs, but I figure it could be useful for people stumbling across this question in the future)
and here : [question]: https://stackoverflow.com/a/489502

Comment: Password is not the issue m entering correct password and i m also able to login via command line on linux.

Comment: check if you can reset your password , and can you kill process mysql and relaunch it again !