# Database connection could not be established. Error number: 1045

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have little problem with my DB. I have a problem with index.php.

Error:

> Warning: mysqli::set_charset(): Couldn't fetch mysqli in
>   /storage/emulated/legacy/htdocs/index.php on line 11 Database
>   connection could not be established. Error number: 1045

Line 10-15 from index.php:

```
$mysql=@new mysqli($db['host'],$db['user'],$db['pass'],$db['name']);
$mysql->set_charset('utf8mb4'); 
if($mysql->connect_errno)
{
    die('Database connection could not be established. Error number: '.$mysql->connect_errno);
}
```

My db:
Database: csgoeco |Collation: utf8mb4_general_ci

[Img1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZpjjV.png)
[Img2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gTvZW.png)
Thx for reply.

Comment: Please check http://stackoverflow.com/q/489119/2298301

Comment: @DhruvSaxena wouldn't u call this as a duplicate

Comment: Check your `$db` array and see if it has the right credentials.

Comment: @rahul It could very well be. Just wanted to be open to the possibility of OP having any other issues despite sifting through the fixes suggested there.