# User is added to MYSQL users with all privileges and still can login

Tags: mysql

Silly question but I have added new user to mysql database and granted all privileges to it but still when I try to log into mysql I've got access denied.

I've performed this steps after I've logged in as a `root`

```
   mysql> CREATE USER 'myuser'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY '123321';
   mysql> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON * . * TO 'myuser'@'localhost';
   mysql> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON * . * TO 'myuser'@'%';
   mysql> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON * . * TO 'myuser'@'127.0.0.1';
   mysql> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

When I run

```
mysql> select User,Host from mysql.user;
```

the result is

```
+----------+-----------+
| User     | Host      |
+----------+-----------+
| myuser   | %         |
| mysql    | %         |
| myuser   | 127.0.0.1 |
| root     | 127.0.0.1 |
| root     | ::1       |
|          | localhost |
| myuser   | localhost |
| root     | localhost |
+----------+-----------+
```

When I try to log with the command

```
mysql -u myuser -p123321
```

The error is that access is denied and password used: Yes.

> ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'myuser'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Comment: Pleas this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/489119/mysql-error-1045-access-denied

Comment: I hope this will help You )

Comment: This is how I've manage to enter as a root in the first place. Still myuser doesn't work

Comment: I've changed also the password for `myuser` from root and still can't log in

Comment: Do you restart Your mysql server?

Comment: Yes, multiple times + server restart

Comment: ok dear friend, please read this post too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10299148/mysql-error-1045-28000-access-denied-for-user-billlocalhost-using-passw

Comment: Finally. One of the answers is fixed the issue: `grant all privileges on *.* to myuser@localhost identified by '123321' with grant option;`. Thanks!

Comment: Great! thank for thous author