# How do I make my machine forget localhost:8080?

Tags: mysql, xampp, mysql-error-1045

Long story short: I've been stuck on error #1045 for a very long time because I decided to change root user password.  I tried everything and anything on SO that revolves around fixing this issue, nothing works.

How do I make it so that I completely wipe out localhost:8080 so I can re download/install Xampp so I can use SQL again?

I tried uninstalling Xampp and re-downloading it but it still remember localhost:8080 resulting in myself getting the error again.

Comment: I guess you need to clean you browser cache, and evt. restart your machine

Comment: @maytham-ɯɐɥʇʎɐɯ if I clear my browser cache, does that mean it'll completely wipe out my browser history?

Comment: @maytham-ɯɐɥʇʎɐɯ I have a macbook which means I did  + F5.  That didn't do anything.  I also tried control + F5, still nothing.

Comment: Seems there are useful suggestions here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/489119/mysql-error-1045-access-denied

Comment: Try `FLUSH HOSTS;`