# MYSQL Access denied for root (pw-reset not working)

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, authentication, debian

I have an interseting problem.
I try to access my mysql server as root (also not wirking with debain-sys-maint) unsing

```
sudo mysql -u root -p
```

I reinstalled complete server (purged all).

```
sudo mysql_secure_installation
```

worked once after reinstall. and then

sudo mysql

worked. But after reset auth to native password I still get this error:

```
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

regardless what i am doing, there is no login to mysql possible.
Any ideas to solve that?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/489119/mysql-error-1045-access-denied

Comment: tanks, already tried that. but i'll try again on new install.

Comment: still no success. after reinstall of mysql-server i was able to use sudo mysql using mysql_secure_installation. I added a root password with UPDATE mysql.user SET authentication_string=PASSWORD('password')  WHERE  User='root'; and FLUSH PRIVILEGES;. I switched to password auth via ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'password'; and FLUSH PRIVILEGES; but  mysql -u root -p
 is still Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES). mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables is also the same.

Comment: /var/log/mysql/error.log: https://pastebin.com/EGF2FUsn

Comment: have you try without password ?

Comment: Yes. No change.

Comment: this is windows menthality to reinstall everything. Linux user never does this. You must start mysql in "single-user-mode", please google for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first stop the service

```
service mysql stop
```

then start mysql in single user mode :

```
mysqld_safe –skip-grant-tables &
```

Then log in without any password

```
mysql
```

then change root'S password "new_pass"

```
UPDATE mysql.user SET password=password(‘new_pass’) WHERE User=’root’;
```

at the end :

```
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
exit;
```

now you are on console again using mysqladmin log in using your new password and shutdown the singleusermode

```
mysqladmin -u root -p shutdown
```

Here shutdown is not the password it is the command, you will be prompted for the password.

then you start the mysql service normally

```
service mysql start
```

Comment: shutdown was not neccessary, bu helpful. restarting the service also worked for me.

Comment: @k1ngarthur but you must exit the singelusermode ?

Comment: Did not remember. I think not. Simply set the Auth type to basic with code above. Because on newer systems Auth for root is done with systems root account.